# Columns with Nan Value getting converted to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with following columns.How to preserve datatype for Column containing Nan to integer

```
Input
1    2     abc
Nan  NaN   xyz

Output
1.0    2.0 abc
Nan  NaN   xyz

Expected
1    2     abc
Nan  NaN   xyz
```

Comment: Nan is a float .... dtype of int has no equivelent

Comment: @JoranBeasley pandas 0.24.2+ has [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/user_guide/integer_na.html) also known as 'Int64' or `pd.Int64Dtype()`.

Comment: Hi Quang,I want to preserve the data type of the column.If its int,it should be int

Answer (score 0):

For version 0.24.+ this might work

`df['Col'] = df['Col'].astype('Int64')`

In Col specify the column you want

Comment: Hi Ritika,if that column has combination of int,string and Nan,how to handle this

Comment: You can't mix numerical values and string in a column. Once you do that, the `dtype` of that column will be labeled as `Object`.